# Google Cast Chromecast SDK Message is malformed (No value for level)

Tags: java, android, json, chromecast

I know this thread is a duplicated of this one, but it is unanswered.

[Receving weird Json Error from custom Chromecast recevier app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540167/receving-weird-json-error-from-custom-chromecast-recevier-app)

I'm trying to cast to a chromecast from an Android application. I followed the following examples from Google.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_basic

I can connect successfully to the chromecast and it shows on the TV my custom html with the app name.

The error comes when i send a video and it says that the JSON has no value for volume. It shows the metadata of the image, name and description, but it doesn't play it

```
public void playOnChromecast() {

    CastSession session =CastContext.getSharedInstance(this).getSessionManager().getCurrentCastSession();

    if(session == null) return;

    MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);

    movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, this.video.getName());
    movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, this.video.getDescription());
    movieMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(this.video.getThumbnail())));
    movieMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(this.video.getThumbnail())));

    MediaLoadOptions.Builder mediaLoadOptionsBuilder = new MediaLoadOptions.Builder();
    mediaLoadOptionsBuilder.setAutoplay(true);
    mediaLoadOptionsBuilder.setPlayPosition(0);

    MediaTrack track = new MediaTrack.Builder(this.video.getId(), MediaTrack.TYPE_VIDEO)
            .setName(this.video.getName())
            .setSubtype(MediaTrack.SUBTYPE_NONE)
            .setContentId(String.valueOf(this.video.getId()))
            .setLanguage("es").build();

    ArrayList<MediaTrack> tracks = new ArrayList<MediaTrack>();
    tracks.add(track);

    JSONObject jsonObj = null;try {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("description", this.video.getDescription());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4")
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
            .setContentType("video/mp4")
            .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
            .setMediaTracks(tracks)
            .setCustomData(jsonObj)
            .build();

    RemoteMediaClient remoteMediaClient = session.getRemoteMediaClient();
    remoteMediaClient.load(mediaInfo, mediaLoadOptionsBuilder.build());
}
```

The result of this is just nothing. In the console I get the following message.

> W/MediaControlChannel: Message is malformed (No value for level);
>   ignoring: (JSON)

Being (JSON) a bunch of JSON data that the SDK sends to the device.

```
{"type":"MEDIA_STATUS","status":[{"mediaSessionId":1,"playbackRate":1,"playerState":"IDLE","supportedMediaCommands":15,"volume":{},"media":{"contentId":"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4","streamType":"BUFFERED","contentType":"video/mp4","metadata":{"metadataType":1,"images":[{"url":"http://cachepicapica.gomovil.co/videos-transcoded/fd42e6b6-b1f8-4eee-87c9-9b024ea41f0b/thumbnail.jpg","width":0,"height":0},{"url":"http://cachepicapica.gomovil.co/videos-transcoded/fd42e6b6-b1f8-4eee-87c9-9b024ea41f0b/thumbnail.jpg","width":0,"height":0}],"title":"Susanita","subtitle":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit"},"tracks":[{"trackId":3,"type":"VIDEO","trackContentId":"3","name":"Susanita","language":"es"}],"customData":{"description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit"}},"currentItemId":1,"extendedStatus":{"playerState":"LOADING","media":{"contentId":"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4","streamType":"BUFFERED","contentType":"video/mp4","metadata":{"metadataType":1,"images":[{"url":"http://cachepicapica.gomovil.co/videos-transcoded/fd42e6b6-b1f8-4eee-87c9-9b024ea41f0b/thumbnail.jpg","width":0,"height":0},{"url":"http://cachepicapica.gomovil.co/videos-transcoded/fd42e6b6-b1f8-4eee-87c9-9b024ea41f0b/thumbnail.jpg","width":0,"height":0}],"title":"Susanita","subtitle":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit"},"tracks":[{"trackId":3,"type":"VIDEO","trackContentId":"3","name":"Susanita","language":"es"}],"customData":{"description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit"}}},"repeatMode":"REPEAT_OFF"}],"requestId":0}
```

I'm seeing in the JSON that volume field is empty, and it should have a level field and mute field. I suppose that that's the error but i don't know how to fix it since that json is built from the Google SDK.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

UPDATE: Tried using a Styled receiver instead and it only worked on an MP4 file but it didn't work on a HLS stream. In both attempts the error shown above did not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i was missing the Cross Origin Resource Headers as described here

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player

Also i noticed that if I used a custom receiver it keeps throwing the error above (Message is malformed).

I used the default styled receiver instead.

It would be nice if Google Cast SDK developers add an error message.